# C# regedit write failed

Tags: c#, .net, regedit

I am developing an application to improve computer performance. For this ***I need to change some DWORD values ​​in Regedit***. But no matter what code I tried, it didn't work.

```
private RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile");

    private void regTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rk.SetValue("SystemResponsiveness", 16, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
```

Comment: *It didn't work* - elaborate

Comment: Probably you don't have a permission.
Run your application as administrator

Comment: Hi, my program is already set to start the administrator automatically

Comment: See if you run as 32 bit app and change the value in wow64 instead of where you expect

Comment: Hi alexrait, I didn't fully understand what you said. Could you please explain step by step?